# A regex boundary in Python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am regular expression newbie. I have a boundary problem to capture a content from a line of string in Python3.

Let's say I have the line of string here:

`line = "(string1),DC (string2),IC\n"`

What I want is `list = ["(string1)", "(string2)"]`

I tried to use

`list = regex.findall("(\(.*\))", line)`

But it returned `list = ["(string1),DC (string2)"]`

Comment: `list = regex.findall(r"\(.*?\)", line)` or `list = regex.findall(r"\([^()]*\)", line)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip '(' and ')' and choose the word between them like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> line = "(string1),DC (string2),IC\n"
>>> re.findall("\(\w+\)", line)
['(string1)', '(string2)']
```